# Getting text bounds in GTK+

Tags: gtk, pango

How can I get bounds of a text, provided string with attributes say, font size, font style, and font family in GTK+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GTK+, you should probably look at [Pango](http://www.pango.org/). I believe the required call is `pango_layout_line_get_pixel_extents()`, although this will of course require you to parse whatever string it is you have with the specs, and set up the corresponding Pango object before getting the extents.